# Prevent Dash Tabs from auto-refreshing while switching in a multi-page app

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Dear Stackoverflow Members

After finding an interesting recommendation [prevent-tabs-from-auto-refreshing-when-switching-between-them](https://community.plotly.com/t/prevent-tabs-from-auto-refreshing-when-switching-between-them/69925/2) on an issue (e.g. switching from `dcc.Tab` without refresh) that I am currently encountering, few additional advice or suggestions are sought on the implementation side, since tabs `t2-t4` are missing.

```
register_page(__name__, path='/')

def buildTabs():
   tb = [
         dcc.Tab(label='tab1', value='t1'),
         dcc.Tab(label='tab2', value='t2'),
         dcc.Tab(label='tab3', value='t3'),
         dcc.Tab(label='tab4', value='t4'),
        ]

def layout():
   tabs = buildTabs()
   layout = dcc.Tabs(id='test_tab', value='t1', children=tabs)
   return layout

   layout = html.Div([
               layout(),
               html.Div(id='qkt', children='bt'),
             ])
```

**N.B**: *I have not been impressed (owing to limitations) with solutions involving the setting of `persistence=True, persistence_type='memory'`  on each `control` held in `dcc.Tab` such as `dcc.Text`, etc.*

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Best

Answer (score 0):

Old problem, but I ran into it today. Was unable to find a favorable solution online. I first tried hiding each tab-div using a callback (style= {'display': 'none'}). This works great, but it is kind of clunky.

After a while, I also tried using the tabs component from Dash Bootstrap Components. This seems to be working as wanted out of the box and is thus the easier solution:

https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/tabs/